# $\min_{\beta_1,...,\beta_3,\beta}\sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{1}{2}||y_i-X_i\beta_i||_2^2+\lambda||\beta||_1$ in augmented Lagrangian form

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Write $\min_{\beta_1,...,\beta_3,\beta}\sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{1}{2}||y_i-X_i\beta_i||_2^2+\lambda||\beta||_1$ in augmented Lagrangian form. s.t. $\beta_1=\beta_2=\beta_3=\beta$

Augmented Lagrangian is defined as:
$L(x,u;p)=f(x)+u^T(Ax-b)+\frac{p}{2}||Ax-b||_2^2$

$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{1}{2}||y_i-X_i\beta_i||_2^2$
$g(x)=\lambda||\beta||_1$

I'm not entirely sure where to go from here. My guess of solution is:

$$\min_{\beta_1,...,\beta_3,\beta}\sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{1}{2}||y_i-X_i\beta_i||_2^2+\lambda||\beta||_1+\frac{p}{2}||(\beta_1-\beta) + (\beta_2-\beta) + (\beta_3-\beta)||_2^2$$
or perhaps the constraints have to be separated
$$\min_{\beta_1,...,\beta_3,\beta}\sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{1}{2}||y_i-X_i\beta_i||_2^2+\lambda||\beta||_1+\frac{p}{2}(||(\beta_1-\beta)||_2^2 + ||(\beta_2-\beta)||_2^2 + ||(\beta_3-\beta)||_2^2)$$

Comment: Why use augmented Lagrangian? You can formulate the problem as $\min_{\beta} \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^3\|y_i-X_i\beta\|^2+\lambda\|\beta\|_1$. This is a convex problem which can be easily solved using accelerated proximal methods.

Comment: @iarbel84 sadly that's just the assignment. It's to run ADMM on it.

Comment: For instance, see §8.2.1 of https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf

Comment: @user8714896 I see. Then the constraints need to be separate, otherwise what you're forcing is $\beta_1+\beta_2+\beta_3=3\beta$, which is different than your original constraint. I think you could also use a different penalty parameter $\rho_i$ for each proximity term

Comment: @iarbel84
so my second answer is correct? If you're willing to put that as an answer I'll up-vote it.

Comment: @user8714896 I posted a detailed answer below. Notice that while it may appear that the proximity term is "joint", it's actually separable as it's comprised of  vectors. If you expend the norm you get the second formulation you put (plus the usual Lagrange multiplier you omitted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a problem of the form:
$$\tag{1}\min_{\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}} f(\mathbf{x}) + g(\mathbf{z}) \\ s.t.: A\mathbf{x}+B\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{c}$$
we construct the augmented Lagrangian:
$$\mathcal{L}_\rho(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z},\mathbf{y})=f(\mathbf{x})+g(\mathbf{z})+\mathbf{y}^T(A\mathbf{x}+B\mathbf{z}-\mathbf{c})+\frac{\rho}{2}\|A\mathbf{x}+B\mathbf{z}-\mathbf{c}\|^2.$$
This could almost fit your model, by setting \begin{aligned}&A=I,\;\mathbf{x}=(\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3)^T\\&B=-I,\mathbf{z}=(\beta,\beta,\beta)^T\\& \mathbf{c}=\mathbf{0}.\end{aligned}
However, your $f(\cdot)$ component has a linear transformation. So in fact, your problem is $$\min_{\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}} f(\mathbf{Ax}) + g(\mathbf{z}) \\ s.t.: \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{0}.$$
We can still follow this framework and construct the augmented Lagrangian:
$$\mathcal{L}_\rho(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z},\mathbf{s})=\frac{1}{2}\|A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^2+\frac{\lambda}{3}\|\mathbf{z}\|_1+\mathbf{s}^T(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{z})+\frac{\rho}{2}\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{z}\|^2.$$
The question is what do you plan to do next. The above formulation is without doubt the augmented Lagrangian. But general ADMM frameworks that are proven to converge to an optimal solution are designed to fit problem $(1)$. Your problem is somewhat different, therefore a generic ADMM algorithm might not work.